# Projection issue when reading in QGIS a GeoTiff exported from Python

Tags: python, export, qgis, geotiff

I am trying to export an RGB geotiff file with Python to be later read and processed in QGIS. The RGB data comes from Landsat and was reprojected to the WSG84 Spatial Reference System.

I am working with the following numpy arrays:

```
    rgb (H, W, 3)
    lons (H, W)
    lats (H, W)
```

Here is the code I use to export the RGB numpy array to a geotiff:

```
    import numpy as np
    from osgeo import gdal, osr
    
    driver = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff')
    options = ['PHOTOMETRIC=RGB', 'PROFILE=GeoTIFF']
    
    # Define the data extent
    extent = [np.min(lons), np.min(lats), np.max(lons), np.max(lats)]
    
    # Get dimensions and set geotransform
    nx = rgb.shape[0]
    ny = rgb.shape[1]
    data_type = gdal.GDT_Byte
    xres = (extent[2] - extent[0]) / float(nx)
    yres = (extent[3] - extent[1]) / float(ny)
    geotransform = (extent[0], xres, 0, extent[3], 0, -yres)
    
    # Create a temp grid
    grid_data = driver.Create('export_rgb.tif', ny, nx, 3, data_type, options=options)
    
    # Setup projection and geo-transform
    # Lat/Lon WSG84 Spatial Reference System
    grid_data.SetGeoTransform(geotransform)
    srs = osr.SpatialReference()
    srs.ImportFromEPSG(4326)
    grid_data.SetProjection(srs.ExportToWkt())
    
    # Write data for each band
    grid_data.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray(rgb[:, :, 0])
    grid_data.GetRasterBand(2).WriteArray(rgb[:, :, 1])
    grid_data.GetRasterBand(3).WriteArray(rgb[:, :, 2])
    
    # Save the file
    grid_data.FlushCache()
    
    # Close the file
    driver = None
    grid_data = None
```

The code runs fine and when testing the output file with gdalinfo, here is what I get:

```
    Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
    Files: ./images/export_rgb.tif
    Size is 2301, 1258
    Coordinate System is:
    GEOGCRS\["WGS 84",
    ENSEMBLE\["World Geodetic System 1984 ensemble",
    MEMBER\["World Geodetic System 1984 (Transit)"\],
    MEMBER\["World Geodetic System 1984 (G730)"\],
    MEMBER\["World Geodetic System 1984 (G873)"\],
    MEMBER\["World Geodetic System 1984 (G1150)"\],
    MEMBER\["World Geodetic System 1984 (G1674)"\],
    MEMBER\["World Geodetic System 1984 (G1762)"\],
    MEMBER\["World Geodetic System 1984 (G2139)"\],
    ELLIPSOID\["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
    LENGTHUNIT\["metre",1\]\],
    ENSEMBLEACCURACY\[2.0\]\],
    PRIMEM\["Greenwich",0,
    ANGLEUNIT\["degree",0.0174532925199433\]\],
    CS\[ellipsoidal,2\],
    AXIS\["geodetic latitude (Lat)",north,
    ORDER\[1\],
    ANGLEUNIT\["degree",0.0174532925199433\]\],
    AXIS\["geodetic longitude (Lon)",east,
    ORDER\[2\],
    ANGLEUNIT\["degree",0.0174532925199433\]\],
    USAGE\[
    SCOPE\["Horizontal component of 3D system."\],
    AREA\["World."\],
    BBOX\[-90,-180,90,180\]\],
    ID\["EPSG",4326\]\]
    Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 2,1
    Origin = (14.558353424072266,4.257406234741211)
    Pixel Size = (0.000494264836152,-0.000148315214168)
    Metadata:
    AREA_OR_POINT=Area
    Image Structure Metadata:
    INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
    Corner Coordinates:
    Upper Left  (  14.5583534,   4.2574062) ( 14d33'30.07"E,  4d15'26.66"N)
    Lower Left  (  14.5583534,   4.0708257) ( 14d33'30.07"E,  4d 4'14.97"N)
    Upper Right (  15.6956568,   4.2574062) ( 15d41'44.36"E,  4d15'26.66"N)
    Lower Right (  15.6956568,   4.0708257) ( 15d41'44.36"E,  4d 4'14.97"N)
    Center      (  15.1270051,   4.1641160) ( 15d 7'37.22"E,  4d 9'50.82"N)
    Band 1 Block=2301x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
    Minimum=0.000, Maximum=255.000, Mean=73.395, StdDev=22.731
    Metadata:
    STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=255
    STATISTICS_MEAN=73.395418042477
    STATISTICS_MINIMUM=0
    STATISTICS_STDDEV=22.730944043107
    STATISTICS_VALID_PERCENT=100
    Band 2 Block=2301x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
    Minimum=0.000, Maximum=255.000, Mean=98.119, StdDev=17.360
    Metadata:
    STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=255
    STATISTICS_MEAN=98.118509336854
    STATISTICS_MINIMUM=0
    STATISTICS_STDDEV=17.360050053259
    STATISTICS_VALID_PERCENT=100
    Band 3 Block=2301x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
    Minimum=0.000, Maximum=255.000, Mean=54.022, StdDev=11.610
    Metadata:
    STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=255
    STATISTICS_MEAN=54.021517222415
    STATISTICS_MINIMUM=0
    STATISTICS_STDDEV=11.610150982507
    STATISTICS_VALID_PERCENT=100
```

The extent of the data looks correct (around 15E / 4N). However, when I import this file into QGIS, I get a completely wrong spatial extent (see screenshot below) which corresponds to the integer dimensions of the data, not the extent in degrees.

[image: QGIS screenshot of RGB layer properties]

Does anyone know what I am missing here?

Comment: It could be a version mismatch between the gdal you write with and the one QGIS uses to read with - that looks like a new style of CRS in the gdalinfo output

Comment: Thanks for your reply! It looks like part of the problem was linked to this (I was using QGIS on a different computer). However I realised there was an additional mistake which caused the lon/lat extent to be slightly off in the geotiff. The x- and y- resolutions were interchanged. Now it works :)